# "Add to Google Calendar" link working when clicked on tutorial site but not when I use it in my own

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, get, google-calendar-api

I am using [this guide](http://taskboy.com/blog/Creating_events_for_Yahoo_and_Google_calendars.html) to better understand how calendar events can be created with HTTP GET requests for Yahoo and Google Calendars. The "Add to Google" calendar link on that page works perfectly for me (opens my Google calendar with a new event with information populated automatically). When I take the format of the link and add my own information, or even just copy and paste the exact same link into my own application, it stops working correctly. My Google Calendar opens with a new event form, but none of the information is being populated correctly. Here is the link as used in the guide:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&amp;text=Joe's+40th+Birthday&amp;details=Joe+turns+40+just+this+once&amp;dates=20111212T190000/20111212T200000&amp;location=Gillette+Stadium
```

Anyone know why this would just stop working when accessed in any way other than clicking on the link in the guide?

Comment: it's not working with the link as posted above, either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL above has several `&amp;` symbols in it, meaning the Google Calendar page is not getting the parameter names it is expecting. When you remove `&amp;` and replace them with a plain &, it works as expected. Without seeing your code, I would you suggest you try adding `.html_safe` to the end of whatever you are using to generate  the URL.